# "Workspace is closed" exception when trying to get the workspace through ResourcesPlugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, resources, workspace

I get this error when trying to get the workspace through ResourcesPlugin:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:339)
```

The code generating this is:

```
IWorkspace ws = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
```

Can you please help with this problem?

Comment: Jut completed my answer with more details on the workspace characteristics.

Answer (score 15):

Does your `Manifest.MF` contain the `org.eclipse.core.resources` in the `Require-bundle` section ?

And do you launch your test as a plugin ? (not as a 'Java Application')

See also [this thread](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t74795.html).

As mentioned in the "[Resources and the file system](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resInt_filesystem.htm)" help page,

> You can access the workspace from the resources plug-in class (defined in `org.eclipse.core.resources`).
>
> When the resources plug-in is not running, the workspace exists solely in the file system and is viewed or manipulated by the user via standard file-based tools. Let's look at what a workspace looks like on disk as we explain the resources plug-in API.

---

From [this book](http://books.google.fr/books?id=6Ob1ANNVcXcC&pg=PA570&lpg=PA570&dq=IWorkspaceRoot+-ResourcesPlugin&source=bl&ots=jlEu8HQjxy&sig=QMWQDyN1OApfWDoCLunV8BFodJ4&hl=fr&ei=rxcsSvnRMd2QjAe1_cT8Cg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#PPA571,M1):

> The workspace directory, regardless of the name defined with the `-data` invocation option, has two roles:
>
> - it acts as the parent for the `.metadata` directory
> - and as the default location for projects
>
> the workspace can contains projects only when:
>
> - the `org.eclipse.core.resources` plugin is included in the configuration and
> - and appropriately started from the workbench
>
> this is automatic from an IDE configuration based on the `org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench` application.

See also [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg10711.html) and remember that:

> the  workspace is a different workspace from the runtime-workspace that's used for testing plugins. When you do Run on an Eclipse PDE environment, it creates a new workspace which is completely empty.

The testing [workspace root can be specified through the "-data"](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg76634.html) launching option.

> If you want to access a file, your best bet is to include it in the plugin itself, and then use `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myfile.txt")` to get an `InputStream` that you can read the contents for.

Comment: The Manifest.MF file contains org.eclipse.core.resources in the Require-bundle section. But I don't want to run the application as a plug-in. I'm not trying to create a plugin. Just to make use of the AST parser in eclipse.

Can I solve this problem and still run the java program as an application?

Comment: As a Java application, you cannot use ResourcesPlugin functions. So you need to access resources though more classic File resources.

Comment: Also, I forgot to say that I found the fisrt web page myself and done whatever is suggested there. Ans still it didn't work. If I use the ResourcesPlugin class from org.eclipse.core.resources, in the method getWorkspace() the workspace is null. That's why the exception is thrown. Why is this happening? Where is the workspace set?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `Plugin.getStateLocation()` in the plugin, it should cause the workspace to be created for you. Without this, you can't save any preferences either. http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg45020.html

http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/Plugin.html#getStateLocation%28%29

Err, sorry -- I just completed necroed this question by accident :)