# how to refresh eclipse workspace programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I am new in eclipse plugin development. I want to refresh my workspace or complete Eclipse programmatically  . so is there any to refresh eclipse programmatically.

Comment: [This](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/6/30/Refreshing-Eclipse-Workspace-using-ANT) can help you.

Comment: @Harry Joy : thanks it's exactly what i needed, refresh eclipse within ant script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh an Eclipse project with Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985976/refresh-an-eclipse-project-with-ant)

Comment: If it's just about ant: You may not even have to program anything: Several kinds of launch configurations, including those for `Ant Build`, have a tab `Refresh` that lets you select what exactly should be refreshed after completion.

Answer (score 21):

Use the [`IResource.refreshLocal()` API](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_When_should_I_use_refreshLocal%3F). You can do this at project root, a particular folder or an individual file. To refresh all projects in a workspace, simply enumerate all projects using `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects()` API and refresh each in turn.

Comment: I get IllegalStateException that the workspace is closed. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a quick snippet to refresh each project in the Eclipse workspace.

```
for(IProject project : ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects()){
    project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, new NullProgressMonitor());
}
```

Comment: I get IllegalStateException that the workspace is closed. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Could be a few things. Are you running Eclipse in a headless way by chance? If so make sure you've actually made a workspace. Also check your plugin manifest settings, try reading this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962364/workspace-is-closed-exception-when-trying-to-get-the-workspace-through-resourc