# Refresh project in eclipse when a new file is added

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse

I found 2 links in the forum but neither really solved my problem. I am creating files in the front end and they get reflected only when i manually refresh the project folder in eclipse... Does any other alternative exist to refresh eclipse automatically?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean to say you're manually adding files in your workspace directory and this does not get reflected in your workspace automatically?

Comment: What did you TRY and what didn't WORK?

Answer (score 7):

Use : **Window->Preferences-> General -> Workspace** and check **Refresh using native hooks and polling** checkbox.
I have verified it. Seems like it polls after few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I am using  Window > Preference > general > worskspace setting .

Answer (score 0):

You should refresh eclipse project programmatically. Take a look on the following discussion: [how to refresh eclipse workspace programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467902/how-to-refresh-eclipse-workspace-programatically)

Once you learn how to implement plug-in that refreshes the project make it to watch your file system an run refresh once your files have been generated.