# How to refresh the workspace in eclipse after adding new files?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I'm creating a web-app using Spring MVC. This app creates some images and saves them into a directory located in the webapp directory and then returns a view like the following:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td><IMG SRC="http://locahost:8180/app/images/image1.png"></IMG></td>
       <td><IMG SRC="http://locahost:8180/app/images/image2.png"></IMG></td>  
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem is I'm not getting the images, I have to do a refresh on Eclipse to get those images.
Any ideas?

Comment: Any files you generate exist in the file system, but are not displayed in Eclipse until you refresh (F5).

Comment: Is there anyway to refresh programmaticaly after adding some new  files?

Comment: you could program your fingers to push F5 XD

Comment: [**This**](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/6/30/Refreshing-Eclipse-Workspace-using-ANT) should help you or [**this SO answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5468283/3928341)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so to elaborate more on the links I put in the comments.

I stumble upon two ways of doing what you need (didn't actually do them but they seemed to work for others):

**1) Refreshing Eclipse Workspace using ANT** [(Answer Link)](http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/6/30/Refreshing-Eclipse-Workspace-using-ANT)

As stated in the link, Eclipse provides several ant tasks that you can use for various purposes, one of which is the `<eclipse.refreshLocal />` tag:

```
<eclipse.refreshLocal resource="MyProject/MyFolder" depth="infinite"/>
```

- *resource* is a resource path relative to the workspace
- *depth* can be one of the following: zero, one or infinite

Furthermore, if you get a **BUILD FAILED** error, make sure you aren't running ANT outside of the Eclipse JRE. To fix this, go open up the External Tools Dialog (Run > External Tools > Open External Tools Dialog...) and make sure the JRE tab is set to "Run in the same JRE as workspace."

**2) Refreshing Eclipse workspace programmatically using the [IResource.refreshLocal()](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_When_should_I_use_refreshLocal%3F) API** [(Answer Link)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5468283/3928341)

As stated in the linked answer, you can do this at project root, a particular folder or an individual file.

To refresh all projects in a workspace, simply enumerate all projects using `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects()` API and refresh each in turn.

Here is another example (from the API website) that sets the contents of a file using a `FileOutputStream`, and then uses `refreshLocal` to synchronize the workspace.

```
   private void externalModify(IFile iFile) throws ... {
      java.io.File file = iFile.getLocation().toFile();
      FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
      fOut.write("Written by FileOutputStream".getBytes());
      iFile.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_ZERO, null);
   }
```