# Run java code error: Workspace is closed

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

To create an automatic project I created a plug-in project with the following dependencies:

1. org.eclipse.core.resources
2. org.eclipse.equinox.registry
3. org.eclipse.core.runtime

And the following java class located in the src folder:

```
package tester;

import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IProgressMonitor;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.NullProgressMonitor;

public class tes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        IProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
        IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
        IProject project = root.getProject("DesiredProjectName");
        try {
            project.create(progressMonitor);
            project.open(progressMonitor);
        } catch (CoreException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

After running the plugin, I ran the java class to create a project in eclipse application, but gave the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
    at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:399)
    at tester.tes.main(tes.java:15)
```

What am I doing wrong? And I apologize for my bad English.

Comment: right click on the project and > open project

Comment: Did you look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962364/workspace-is-closed-exception-when-trying-to-get-the-workspace-through-resources

Comment: Yes I saw some related questions, but I could not solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't just start using Eclipse resources in the `main` class of an ordinary Java program. You have to start Eclipse using either the `eclipse` command or by specifying the `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main` main class. This is because there is a lot of initialization that needs to be done before the workspace can be made available.

To run a 'headless' Eclipse application you should use the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension point to define an application and the class to run for the application. Something like:

```xml
<extension
     id="appname"
     point="org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications">
  <application
        cardinality="singleton-global"
        thread="main"
        visible="true">
     <run
           class="package.Application">
     </run>
  </application>
</extension>
```

You specify this application id on the `-application` parameter of the `eclipse` command.