# M2M transformation : erreurs Eclipse Workspace closed // Content is not allowed in prolog // Null pointer

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to do a transformation between two models, 
every things seems to be ok except the use of the eclipse in standalone mode,
I got errors when trying to execute the tansformation programatically from java,

How to solve that? its urg. Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Errors :

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workspace is closed.
>       at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:399)

```
File f = new File(Path);            
URI transformationURI = URI.createFileURI(f.getAbsolutePath()); 
resource = resourceSet.getResource(transformationURI, true);`
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1DiagnosticWrappedException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>       at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.handleDemandLoadException(ResourceSetImpl.java:315)
>       at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:274)
>       at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:397)

When i omit the line :

```
//resource = resourceSet.getResource(transformationURI, true);
```

I get an other exception :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at org.eclipse.m2m.qvt.oml.TransformationExecutor.doLoad(TransformationExecutor.java:205)
>       at org.eclipse.m2m.qvt.oml.TransformationExecutor.loadTransformation(TransformationExecutor.java:108)
>       at org.eclipse.m2m.qvt.oml.TransformationExecutor.execute(TransformationExecutor.java:137)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.eclipse.m2m.internal.qvt.oml.compiler.UnitResolverFactory$Registry$1.readFactories(UnitResolverFactory.java:66)
>       at org.eclipse.m2m.internal.qvt.oml.compiler.UnitResolverFactory$Registry$1.(UnitResolverFactory.java:44)
>       at org.eclipse.m2m.internal.qvt.oml.compiler.UnitResolverFactory$Registry.(UnitResolverFactory.java:43)
>       ... 6 more

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run java code error: Workspace is closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839197/run-java-code-error-workspace-is-closed)

Comment: It does not solve the problem. I think it's related to the config of the standalone mode. Does anyone have an idea how to do it? thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your program just a plain Java program? If so the answer applies.

Comment: my program is an application

Comment: Do you mean an Eclipse application or something else? If it is an Eclipse application are you calling `PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench`?

Comment: an Eclipse application, no

Comment: Please show your `IApplication` class

Comment: Is it necessary to call PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench; and how?

Comment: The original answer applies if this is not an Eclipse application. If you want to use Eclipse code you **must** create an Eclipse application.

Comment: "Please show your IApplication class" how do it?

Answer (score 0):

As covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839197/run-java-code-error-workspace-is-closed) you must run an Eclipse application to ensure all the necessary Eclipse setup is completed.

For a 'headless' application which does not have a UI the `IApplication` class can be very simple:

```java
public class Application implements IApplication
{
  @Override
  public Object start(final IApplicationContext context)
    throws Exception
  {
    .. your code here ...

    return IApplication.EXIT_OK;
  }

  @Override
  public void stop()
  {
    // No action
  }

  private static void ensurePluginStarted(String id)
  {
    Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(id);
    if (bundle != null)
     {
       if ((bundle.getState() & Bundle.ACTIVE) == 0)
        {
          try
           {
             bundle.start(Bundle.START_TRANSIENT);
           }
          catch (BundleException ex)
           {
             ex.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

This application can use the Eclipse workspace but not the UI. In some cases it may be necessary to call the `ensurePluginStarted` method to ensure that all the plug-ins you are going to use are running. Any plug-in which tries to use the UI will fail.

If you want a UI then a full Eclipse RCP is required.

Comment: hi greg-449, The mentioned solution does not much in my case, I run a java application in a standalone eclipse. what can i do to run my qvto transformation from my java application without the mentionned errors. thanks a lot.

Comment: You cannot access the Eclipse workspace from a plain Java application.