# Workspace is closed

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to run my plugin as an application and I get the following 
error:

```
java.lang.illegalstateexception: workspace is closed.

at org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace(ResourcesPlugin.java:407)
```

I call the method ResourcesPlugin.getworkspace() on the line which is 
pointed out by the exception.

**Code**

```
IProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
```

I am using Eclipse plugin project. How do I resolve this?

Comment: You should add Eclipse as a tag. Did you look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962364/workspace-is-closed-exception-when-trying-to-get-the-workspace-through-resourc

Comment: You have to write an Eclipse headless RCP to use the workspace in an application. Are you doing that?

Comment: how to write Eclipse headless RCP ? can you suggest any link for this?

Comment: How are you launching your project? What *kind* of launcher is it?

Comment: Just to be clear code using Eclipse resources like this must be run as a plugin in Eclipse or in an Eclipse RCP (with a GUI or 'headless'). It will not run in a plain Java application. Google 'eclipse headless rcp'